# Select specific columns using find in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel how can I get specific columns using find? I know you can do it with get like this:

```
$user = User::where('u_id', '=', 1)
        ->get(['firstname', 'lastname']);
```

Is there a way to do it with find? This is what I currently have:

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

Comment: `$user = User::select('firstname', 'lastname')->find(1);` should work

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBaker: If you post your answer, I'll select yours.

Comment: `$user = User::select(['firstname', 'lastname'])->find(1);`

Answer (score 15):

You have two options.

First, you can pass the columns to select as the second parameter to `find()`:

```
$user = User::find(1, ['firstname', 'lastname']);
```

Second, although somewhat specialized, `find()` is just the method used to execute the query, so you can modify the query as normal beforehand (add selects, wheres, orders, etc.). Therefore, you can just add a `select()` before you execute the `find()`:

```
$user = User::select(['firstname', 'lastname'])->find(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, similar to @patricus.

```
$did = User::findOrFail($id, ['first_name', 'last_name']);
```